# Mongo database fails to be ready every other test run

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mocha.js

I'm using Mocha to run tests on my Express (well, Keystone) server, which uses Mongoose/MongoDB. In the `before` Mocha hook, I drop the database, then initialize the models, then load in some fixtures, all controlled in an async.series call so I have some assurance that these things are happening sequentially.

One of the tests fails every other run. The test makes an API call which executes a geo query on the database. It fails with:

```
․{ [MongoError: Unable to execute query: error processing query: ns=test.locations limit=50 skip=0
Tree: GEONEAR  field=lnglat.geo maxdist=5000 isNearSphere=0
Sort: {}
Proj: {}
 planner returned error: unable to find index for $geoNear query] name: 'MongoError' }
․TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

and then on the next run it succeeds. And then the next it fails. And so on, invariably.

Is there some way I can check whether the database is ready to have these tests run on it? For bonus credit, what in the world would cause this consistent alternation?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your code organization is similar to this:

**server.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var express = require('express');

var db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/my-database');
var app = express();

db.connection.once('connected', function() {

    require('./lib/api_routes')(app);
    app.listen(3000, function() {
        console.log('listening on 3000');
    }

    app.emit('dbLoaded');
});

exports = module.exports = app;
```

**lib/api_routes.js**

```
module.exports = function(app) {
    app.get('/api/my_route', function(req, res) {
        ...
    }
}
```

**test/my_test.js**

```
var app = require('../server');

before(function(done) {
    app.on('dbLoaded', function() {
        console.log('db is connected');
        done();
    }
}

before(function() {
    ... your test initialization code
}
```

Express inherits [the 'events' module](http://nodejs.org/api/events.html). your db connection is doing the same thing with `db.connection.once()`. It will only execute... once the db is connected! In that function you are then emitting an event that let's your `before()` hook know to execute it's callback, kicking off the next hook/test in your test suite.

As a side note, you don't need the async library to run your test setup asynchronously. If you pass your `before()` hooks a callback, Mocha will run them asynchronously on it's own. You can have a `before()` block for each setup task you want to run.